# How to identify whether the text changed in textbox either by programmatically or by user

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, textbox, textchanged

We are using a TextBox to display input received from the I/O system. If the user enters some data on the text box, the value will be written to the IO system.

We are using the OnTextChanged event to write the data entered by the user to the IO system.

The problem is that we get this event when we update the value received from the IO system to the text box (from the code).

Is it possible to know whether the value of the TextBox is changed by the user or by using the code?

Comment: Use bindings and MVVM. Don't put logic into view.

Comment: No i need to find this difference in text changed event for internal purposes

Comment: Compare the text with your model. If it differs it was user input

Comment: Or take another Event like KeyDown

Comment: It's not possible to find this out in the `TextChanged` event handler. Do whatevery you want to do before setting the `Text` property programmatically?

Comment: I had this exact problem recently. In my case, the code would initialize the TextBox before the user would see it and have a chance to change the text. So in the TextChanged event, I check to see if IsKeyboardFocused is true, if it is, I can safely assume the change is the result of user input.

Comment: @Jim Foye is it it for UWP or wpf?

Comment: This is for a WPF application

Comment: Im actually looking for a solution in UWP

Answer (score 1):

You could set a Boolean variable named **IsUserInput**, after the I/O system sends data to the text box, you need to set IsUserInput to false.
In the `KeyDown` event of the TextBox, the variable can be set to true. Finally, you could use this variable to determine the text inputter in the `textChanged` event.

Please refer to the following code.

```
public Boolean IsUserInput;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsUserInput = false;
            myTextBox.Text = "hellohello";
          
        }

        private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsUserInput)
            {
//write data to I/O sytem
            }
           
        }

private void myTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsUserInput = true;
        }
```